# How to combine data from multiple CloudKit tables?

Tags: ios, swift, model, cloudkit

I'm looking for a way to loading data from multiple CloudKit tables into one object.
Now I'm loading the data from one CloudKit Table (recordType), but how can I combine this data within the function below? I need to add the Activities table connected to the Clients table. So one Client can have multiple Activities.

My Client model:

```
class Client: NSObject {
  var recordID: CKRecordID!
  var name: String?
  var activities: [Activity]?
  var image: UIImage?
  var email: String?
  var phone: String?
  var rate: Int?
}
```

My Activity object:

```
class Activity: NSData {
  var name: String?
  var date: Date?
}
```

Function for loading only Clients:

```
private func loadClients() {
    let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Name", ascending: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Clients", predicate: pred)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    var newClients = [Client]()

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
      let client = Client()
      client.recordID = record.recordID
      client.name = record["Name"] as? String
      client.email = record["Email"] as? String
      client.phone = record["Phone"] as? String
      client.rate = record["Rate"] as? Int

      newClients.append(client)
    }

    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if error == nil {
          ViewController.isDirty = false
          self.clients = newClients

          if self.clients.count == 0 {
            self.messageLabel.text = "No values in the database"
          } else {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
          }

          self.updateView()
        } else {
          self.messageLabel.text = "Error loading data"
          print("ERROR: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
          self.updateView()
        }
      }
    }

    CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.add(operation)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to load `Client` with `Activity` array using one request.

I think that's not possible using `CloudKit`.
But you can load `Activities` after receiving `Client` record:

```
    if let activitiesIDs = clientRecord["activities"] as? [CKRecordID] {
        let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: activitiesIDs)
        operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (records, error) in

        }

        let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        database.add(operation)
    }
```